# Exclude folder from Active Directory authorization

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, active-directory, authorization

Is there any way to exclude a folder from Active Directory authorization in an Azure Web App written in ASP.NET WebPages (not MVC)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to allow all user using a location section in the web.config ?

```
<configuration>
  <location path="path to your directory">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration
```

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened. Maybe setting no default authorization in azure and deny users for specific folder could work, but is it possible to specify name or group of users in AD for <deny users="..">?

Comment: Are your groups loaded in the Roles of the ASP.NET Identity ? If yes I think you can use the allow roles directive: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0(v=vs.85).aspx ?